# What is the most robust way to install and run Redis on Windows Server 2012? (Updated for 2018)

Tags: redis, windows-server-2012

I know this question has been asked before, but it was asked back in 2014. The proposed solution was running Microsoft's port of Redis. However, that port hasn't been touched since 2016.

Comment: I agree with the need for an update on this. The lack of guidance in the documentation is disappointing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, "Not Recommended" is the official answer:

https://redislabs.com/ebook/appendix-a/a-3-installing-on-windows/

> Before we get into how to install Redis on Windows, I’d like to point
>   out that running Redis on Windows isn’t recommended, for a variety of
>   reasons. In this section we’ll cover these points:
>
> Reasons why you shouldn’t be running Redis on Windows. How to
>   download, install, and run a precompiled Windows binary. How to
>   download and install Python for Windows. How to install the Redis
>   client library.

But even that ebook page (next page) points to the now archived MSFT Redis project.

I would go with running Redis in Docker
https://hub.docker.com/r/_/redis/

Comment: Thanks, Patrick. Running Redis (if that's even what I end up going with) in some sort of virtual environment will be how I proceed.

Answer (score 3):

OK... that answer is Good and Official but this one is the future.

Windows Linux Subsystem supports fork (the reason they say it is not recommended) and I was able to run the RQ tutorial on my Windows 10 laptop.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Comment: Yep, it was super easy to get Redis running on my dev machine using this. But alas, it's not on Windows Server 2012. But thanks for the additional suggestion!